# Migrate UniFi AP to new UniFi Controller (without losing settings)

Tags: unifi

I was running my UniFi Controller on a Raspberry Pi when my SD card failed. The UniFi AP that was previously connected to that controller is still working normally.

So I'll have to re-setup a new UniFi Controller and connect the AP to this the controller. How can I do that without losing the settings that are already provisioned on the AP?

The solutions I found online involve backing up settings from the old Controller, but obviously those solutions are not applicable in my case.

Comment: The AP gets its settings from the Controller, not the other way round. Where is your backup?

Comment: @MichaelHampton None, unfortunately. So now the AP would continue working normally without a controller, but once I connect it to a brand new controller, it will get brand new (factory-reset-like) settings?